# Designing a macro which clicks a link to download an XLS file and copies that file into the worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need help designing a macro in excel that:

1. Navigates to a web address which downloads an XLS file (going to the address will automatically download the XLS file so this doesn't need to be automated)
2. Copies the contents of the first sheet of the downloaded file (call it "sheet1")
3. Pastes sheet1 into the original workbook
4. Deletes the XLS file that was downloaded

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried searchinng on Google, and using the Excel Macro Recorder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, first, you could try searching on Google for information relevant to your task.

1) I did that (search string: "*excel vba url download to file*") and lo and behold, the SECOND page returned was on the **MrExcel** website with an answer from Excel MVP and '*friend of all learners*' Colo:

[VBA - Save a file from a Website](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/67123-visual-basic-applications-save-file-website.html#post318584)

2) your next task in Excel would be to use the Macro recorder (*Tools>Macro>Record New Macro...*) to record the steps of opening the file you downloaded. This will give you some code to look at and start learning.

3) Next, again using the Macro recorder, copy the data from the newly opened excel file into your macro workbook. This will give you some code to look at and start learning.

4) Now you can look on Google for **Excel VBA Delete file on drive** which again, will give you the answer.

Any problems, let us know.

Happy to have helped

Philip

Comment: Lol, yeah sorry for some reason the MrExcel site is blocked at work, but I was able to get on it from my home computer and find the code I needed.